# What is the result of modifying the reagents in the Sanger method?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing

If one of the dideoxynucleotides is omitted while using the Sanger method how would that affect the chain termination method of DNA sequencing?

Comment: Are you talking that you don't put in a whole base (like T) or if you have a deletion?

Comment: if by one of the dideoxynucleotides, you mean one of ddatp, or.ddctp, ddgtp, or ddttp was ommited from the process, then the sequencing would only be able to terminate for the other three dideoxynucleotides. And you would not be able to get the full sequence, and only nucleotides of whatever three you had.

Comment: @RoSiv if you have an answer then post that as an answer. Comments should be used only to seek clarification or suggest improvements.

Comment: @user18817 you would possibly benefit from familiarizing yourself with the BiologySE homework policy: http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework

Comment: @WYSIWYG         I was not sure if I was right. I am only an undergrad and I dont wanna give out a wrong answer to someone. Sorry.

Comment: @RoSiv Then provide a good answer with references. You are right. Just make it a bit elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

If by one of the dideoxynucleotides, you mean one of ddATP, ddCTP, ddGTP, or ddTTP was omitted from the process, then the sequencing would only be able to terminate for the other three dideoxynucleotides. And you would not be able to get the full sequence, and only nucleotides of whatever three you had.

The function of ddNTPs (the dideoxnucleotides) is to stop the elongation of DNA and to subsequently be read by either fluorescence or radioactivity.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanger_sequencing

Comment: Note that in Sanger sequencing the ddNTPs are not added together in the same mix. If you omit one ddNTP then you won't be able to sequence that particular base in the DNA. Though you may be able to infer the 4th base from the other three, the confidence of the read would be low.